# Prove that if G is a continuous function defined on [a, b] such that G′(x) = 0 for all x ∈ (a, b), then G(x) is constant on [a, b]

Tags: calculus

> Use the Mean Value Theorem to prove that if G is a continuous function defined on [a, b] such that G′(x) = 0 for all x ∈ (a, b), then G(x) is constant on [a, b]

**My Thoughts:**

- I mean its obvious, if the gradient is 0 for all points in the
  interval, this means that its a line parallel to the x axis (Gradient
  zero).
- The Mean Value Theorem says that if the average slope is $c$, then
  there must be at least one point in the interval $m ∈ (a, b)$ where
  $G'(m)=c$.

How do I combine these two ideas together and give a mathematical proof?

I thought about this for quite sometime. The answer is worth 6 marks, and I can't give any good explanation/mathematical proof which deserves 6 marks. It seems like common sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$G(x)-G(a)=G'(c)(x-a)=0\implies G(x)=G(a)$$
for all $x\in [a,b]$.

Comment: +1 What does $G' (c) (x-a)$ mean here? What is $c$ in your answer btw?

Comment: do you know mean value theorem ? $c$ is an element in $(a,x)$ s.t. $G(x)-G(a)=G'(c)(x-a)$ (that exist by mean value theorem). Notice that by mean value theorem I only proved that $G(x)=G(a)$ on $[a,b[$. The fact that $G(a)=G(b)$ needs an other justification.

Comment: Oh got it. Because I am too used to $$G'(c)=\frac{G(a)-G(b)}{(a-b)}$$ that your way of representing seemed unfamiliar. Basically they are the same thing.